# Gradle sync failed in Android Studio processRequest = (req, res, next) => {

Tags: node.js, react-native, android-studio

I just come across this issue in a newly created react native project. I'm using node 14.17.0 via nvm. And running `yarn start` worked just fine from the Mac terminal. But syncing project in Android Studio still failed. Any help?

```
/Users/me/project/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:350
  processRequest = (req, res, next) => {
                 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/me/project/node_modules/metro/src/shared/output/bundle.js:12:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
```

Answer (score 4):

I solved this problem with this command in the terminal

```
sudo ln -s $(which node) /usr/local/bin/node
```